# In Typescript: Is there a way to initialize an object or array inline (with a certain interface type)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In Typescript I want to do something like this:

```
interface SomeType {
 name: string
}
useState([]:SomeType[]); // This creates an empty array of SomeType inline & calls a function called useState
```

or even

```
function getArrayOfSomeType():SomeType[] {
  return []:SomeType[];
}
```

Other cases might involve the same concept but with a map/dictionary:

```
// Maybe there is a better way to declare maps?
interface MapOfSomeTypes {
 [key:string]: SomeType
}

function getMapOfTypes():MapOfSomeTypes {
  return {} as MapOfSometypes; // or perhaps {}:MapOfSomeTypes
}
```

This is to get around having to declare these before and then returning them or passing them to another function when all I need is an empty version of them (like for react-hooks).

Comment: Is there any problem with `useState([]);` or `return []` correspondingly?

Comment: I am probably missing something but with react's `useState` it looks like: `const [elementOfSomeType, functionThatTakesSomeType] = useState({}); ` and I can't figure out how to declare the types for them without initializing an empty object outside of this line with type:`SomeType`. Since `useState` is likely taking  a generic type I think I need to declare that somewhere to make all the types match.

Comment: I'm not sure how code from your comment correlates with your original question. Hence, is there a reason to declare a type explicitly? Cannot TS infer it for you?

Comment: See above, just clarified shortly after you replied but it can't really infer it because I believe `useState` is taking a generic.

Comment: I did see it, my question still stands: any problem with NOT declaring the type explicitly and using type inference?

Comment: `useState([] as SomeType[])`?

Comment: That works for the array type @JuanMendes but when I do it for `useState({} as MapOfSomeTypes )` I get this error in my linter: `type assertion on object literals is forbidden, use a type annotation instead`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to declare them explicitly - typescript would infer it for you, hence

```
interface SomeType {
 name: string
}
useState([]);
```

```
function getArrayOfSomeType():SomeType[] {
  return [];
}
```

```
interface MapOfSomeTypes {
 [key:string]: SomeType
}

function getMapOfTypes():MapOfSomeTypes {
  return {};
}
```

Comment: This example is not not inferring it, you're creating a function that basically casts an inferred `any[]` to the return type of the function?

Comment: @JuanMendes how can you tell that?

Comment: If you don't explicitly say `SomeType[]` as the return value of getArrayOfSomeType(), it will be inferred to be `any[]`. However,  your function casts it to `SomeType[]` when it returns it?

Comment: "If you don't explicitly say SomeType[] as the return value, it will be any[]," --- how can you tell that? What makes you think it's not inferred based on the argument or return value type? Or at least that it's not inferred as `[]` type?

Comment: It's inferred by the caller of `getArrayOfSomeType`, but within the function, it's just as if you had instead done `return [] as SomeType[]`, so you're just hiding the casting behind the function, but it's still casting

Comment: @JuanMendes "but it's still casting" --- how can you tell that? Any chance you prove it? Why do you think it's not typed as `[]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202071/discussion-between-juan-mendes-and-zerkms).

Comment: I must have been making another mistake in my code elsewhere. This seems to work now and inference does work. Thanks